# How to manually postprocess CMake target during installation?

Tags: installation, cmake, gdb, elf

I am working on a library that provides gdb pretty-printers. They could be automatically located by including the [`.debug_gdb_scripts`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/dotdebug_005fgdb_005fscripts-section.html) section in the generated binary. For binaries inside `build`, I would like this section to point to the pretty-printer inside the source tree. For installed binaries, I would like to either strip this specific section only, or install the pretty-printer as well and change the reference to its installed location.

Is there builtin functionality in CMake or a simple solution to postprocess the installed binary?

Comment: I don't understand the specifics, but it seems you need capability to run custom commands post build, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html - POST_BUILD event.

Comment: There's [`install(SCRIPT/CODE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#code).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just put the pretty printer inline into the `.debug_gdb_scripts` section?

Comment: @Kamath What I would need would be a POST_INSTALL event, but I guess install(SCRIPT/CODE) is as close as you can get? CMake already supports installing stripped binaries and adjusting RPATH, so I was hoping there would be a way to hook into that tooling.

Comment: @ssbssa mostly worried about the auto-load safe-path here - for embedded scripts, the binary is probably not in the $debugdir or $datadir/auto-load, which is the gdb default. If I installed my pretty-printer script in one of those paths, they could be loaded automatically.